# Did Walt's final victory over Gus reflect luck or Walt actually outsmarting Gus?

Tags: breaking-bad

(Spoilers in a general way)
Walt was well aware of Gus' world-class intelligence and beyond that, almost supernatural intuition -- somehow Gus, for no reason a normal person would have access to, knew that taking is car was unsafe.

In a lot of movies and shows, that would be the end of the bomb but Walt tried it in a different context. It seems to me that Walt understood from talking to Jesse that Gus felt safe in Hector's presence -- as sadistic as it was towards Hector, sitting by Hector's wheelchair in the nursing home was almost a recreational activity for Fring. He could relax knowing that no matter how extraordinarily dangerous Hector once was, he was utterly harmless now.

Did Walt, using intuition that rivaled Fring's own, understand that using Hector was the one plan that would work because of this feeling of safety that Gus had with Hector or was Walt simply lucky, nearly out of ideas and fortunately for him, his last idea was his best one?

Answer (score 5):

You're asking the wrong question, in the sense that it's not always as clear cut when something is luck and when it is skill.

In either direction, characters can lie, be mistaken, be misguided, or make a bad judgment. What's more, double bluffs can also happen, where a character thinks they're right even though they're not, and they still luck into the outcome they envisaged. It totally looks like they were right but they were not.

Luck vs skill is not definitively attributable *unless* the plot chooses to explicitly disambiguate it, which in this case it doesn't.

Many plots rely on some kind of serendipity to resolve, but this does not in any way diminish the skill/effort that was also required for the plot resolution.
Whether it is Samwise snooping on Frodo and Gandalf's conversation, an unwitting Luke managing to buy that exact R2D2 droid, or Neo happening to survive the ship crash in Machine City that Trinity didn't; the existence of that serendipity does not negate any other achievements.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I loved, *Loved*, **Loved** this show and its complex characters.

Gus, is shown to be shrewd, cruel and just plain smart, a genius criminal mastermind.  Walt on the other hand was sometimes too weak for his own good, out of his element at times and a poor planner as the series later showed.  However, his Heisenberg persona was able to create what TVTropes calls a [Batman Gambit](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BatmanGambit)

> A plan that revolves entirely around people doing exactly what you'd expect them to do. This trope relies heavily on Flaw Exploitation manipulating, remembering that "flaws" include "virtues" as well. Sometimes the flaw is that the villains are so predictable that they'll take the first chance they have to do something mean and underhanded. Other times, the flaw is that the heroes are so heroic that they'll act for the greater good without even thinking about it. One might recognize the fact that heroes always win — and design a plan based on the assumption that they will succeed.

Gus' virtues were many but his main flaw was **Pride** as he believed he beat everyone thoroughly and completely.  It was his hubris in gloating to Tio that he had eliminated the entirety of his family that proved his undoing:

From the TVTropes section of Breaking Bad explaining Walter's Batman Gambit:

> When his initial attempt to kill Gus fails, he acquires Hector Salamanca as an ally, convinces him to talk to the DEA so Gus will think he's snitching, then booby-traps his wheelchair. This plan hinges on the hopes that a) Héctor hates Gus more than he hates Walt, b) Gus will insist on killing Héctor in person and c) Héctor is willing to kill himself to take Gus down with him. Amazingly, it all works.

So, to answer your question.  It's not luck, at least not completely.  Not just intelligence either, as it required cooperation from another party.  It is a combination of the two with a dash of persistence and courage - Walt just outmaneuvered Gus